# What HTTP origin does GM_xmlhttpRequest send?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, cors, userscripts, gm-xmlhttprequest

I want my app with a REST API to be accessible in different flavors:

- From the same domain (use normal AJAX request here)
- From another domain via script attached by site owner (CORS)
- From another domain via userscript (GM_xmlhttpRequest (?))

I want to limit the list of sites for my app to be accessible from by a whitelist.

I know how to do it with CORS but I'm not sure if it works with `GM_xmlhttpRequest` the same way since `GM_xmlhttpRequest` does not require the `Origin` header to be sent back from a server.

I don't care for a client but I still need to check on a server from which site the request was sent and answer with something like `{response:"site not supported"}` if it isn't in a whitelist.

So, when I run a userscript on some webpage and make a `GM_xmlhttpRequest`, can the server detect the origin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use the `Origin` header to reliably restrict access by userscripts to your API.

By default, [`GM_xmlhttpRequest()`<sup>Doc</sup>](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_xmlhttpRequest) does not send the `Origin` header at all.  Nor does `GM_xmlhttpRequest` block cross-site requests; that is the main reason that `GM_xmlhttpRequest` exists.

Also, **for *Greasemonkey* (Firefox) and *Tampermonkey* (Chrome)**, `GM_xmlhttpRequest` does not send the `referer` header, by default.

However, *both* **headers can be overridden** to be whatever the script-writer wants.

Here is a demo script that spoofs both headers (use a packet sniffer to see for yourself):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        _Test Fake Referrer
// @include     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18178934/*
// @grant       GM_xmlhttpRequest
// ==/UserScript==

GM_xmlhttpRequest ( {
    method:     "GET",
    url:        "http://www.google.com",
    headers:    {
        referer:  "http://microsoft.com",
        origin:   "http://microsoft.com"
    }
} );
```

---

**A plain Chrome userscript** is not so kind to the script developer.  Native Chrome userscripts never send the `Origin` header and always send the current page as the `referer`.

If you try to spoof either of these headers, the console will show errors like:

> Refused to set unsafe header "referer"
>   Refused to set unsafe header "origin"

This is one more reason to use Tampermonkey for your Chrome userscripts.